# Which file system supports RAID and is mature enough for a media server?

Tags: 13.04, server, filesystem, raid, zfs

I am planning on setting up a home media machine with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS or 13.04 (please let me know if this makes a difference).

I have 4 hard drives and I am looking for a file system that supports raid and will be resistant to one or two hard drive failures. I would prefer to have a file system with the least amount of problems that would lead to lost data or system crashing.

I have some experience with ZFS on FreeBSD, but I am not sure if zfs on linux is mature enough. Does anyone have any experience or knows a website where I can read up on how the different filesystems compare currently?

Comment: I con only offer these 2 links: http://rudd-o.com/linux-and-free-software/ways-in-which-zfs-is-better-than-btrfs http://pthree.org/2012/04/17/install-zfs-on-debian-gnulinux/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditionally raid is implemented below the filesystem layer, so you can use whatever filesystem you like.  ZFS does it in the filesystem, but is not in a production usable state on Linux.  Btrfs also is trying to do the same, but again, isn't in a production quality state.  `mdadm` software raid can handle replacing failed disks in redundant configurations ( levels other than 0 ), and can reshape the array between most levels or add and remove disks without data loss.

In any case, it is important to remember that raid is no substitute for backups; its purpose is to avoid downtime in the event of disk failure, not protect data from any of the myriad of ways it can be lost.

Answer (score 0):

RAID is more a hardware configuration and I do not think it matters what file system you use. Unless you have a specific reason use EXT4. I think it is more important to have backups then use any particular file system.

Comment: I would prefer to use a non-hardware RAID (RAID-Z-like) to make it easier to move the data if some hardware piece fails.The purpose of the machine is to be the backup for my other machines (I hope that my main machines and the media machine will not fail at the same time)